# Demora no carregamento de página PHP com imagem

Tags: php

Tenho uma página PHP que carrega os 570 registros em 2 segundos.

O problema é que quando insiro imagens, mesmo que pequenas (3 KB) o tempo de carregamento vai para 10 segundos.

Tem alguma forma de carregar essas imagens?

```
    <?php 
    while($consulta1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1)){;  
    ?>

    <div class="relacao">
      <div class="nome-album-artista"><?php echo $consulta1["nm_album"].'<br><i>'.$consulta1["nm_cantor"].'</i>'; ?></div>
    </div>

    <div id="botoes">
      <div class="btn_alterar"><a href="album_alterar.php?album=<?php echo $consulta1["id_album"]?>" title="Alterar"><img src="images/valid-icon.png"></a></div>
    </div>

    <?php
    }
    mysql_free_result($result1); 
    mysql_close($conn)
    ?>
```

Comment: Se a única imagem usada é a "images/valid-icon.png" e ela tem 3K realmente não existe motivo para demorar salvo algum problema de comunicação ou no servidor. Ou tem alguma outra coisa errada em outro lugar. Ou seja, o problema provavelmente é em algo que não está aparente neste trecho de código. Ou eu comi bola em alguma coisa.

Comment: você tem alguma coisa especifica que pode estar atrapalhando no carregamento? ao meu ver era para estar normal

Comment: Deve ser loop infinito do while, não?

Comment: bigown, na verdade não é sempre essa imagem, eu carrego as capas dos álbuns de acordo com o select, só coloquei essa imagem ai para testar, pq ela é bem menor

Comment: André Ribeiro, acho que não, pois removi o link da imagem e o tempo de carregamento ficou o mesmo...

Comment: @GuilhermeHenrique, pior que não consegui identificar nada :/

Comment: @WallaceMaxters, acredito que não. Pois se removo as imagens ele carrega super rápido

Comment: @Ricardo aí é que está, se você coloca um código diferente do que está dando problema, fica difícil analisar, este pode estar ok e o real pode estar com problema. Se você estiver carregando 570 imagens diferentes (ou pelo menos URLs diferentes mesmo que cada uma tenha 3K, serão quase 2MB e aí justifica o tempo.

Comment: @bigown mas o código que postei está dando o problema que mencionei, está levando cerca de 10 segundos para carregar. Antes, quando usava a capa do álbum estava levando cerca de 20 seg. Ai removi a imagem e depois troquei por essa para ver se diminuia o tempo, entendeu?

Comment: Não há um problema no código apresentado e acho pouco provável que alguém consiga achar qual é o problema que deve estar em outro lugar.

Comment: Teria como postar o print da pagina carregada mostrando a tag (network) ? ela vai exibir quanto tempo demorou cada ação

Comment: @PauloHDSousa, do Firebug vc diz?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mais uma possibilidade para você é carregar as imagens apenas quando elas realmente forem necessárias. Um projeto chamado Lazy Load (jQuery) faz exatamente isso. Ele fará com que as imagens sejam carregadas apenas quando elas estiverem no viewport do usuário.

**Site do projeto:**

http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

Comment: Não conhecia esse Lazy Load, ficou perfeito!

Comment: Fico feliz por ter ajudado :)

Answer (score 3):

Talvez você não encontre a solução do seu problema aqui, pois é um caso muito diferente que aborda muitas teorias sobre redes, memória, etc..Então exclui todas as possibilidade do problema está em seu código.

No entanto, quero lhe apresentar o **YSlow** como RESPOSTA da sua questão. Ele oferece sugestões para melhorar o desempenho da página e resume os componentes da sua página.

**YSlow** analisa as páginas web e por que elas estão lentas. Feita para sites de alto desempenho.

**Download:** http://yslow.org/

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559355/how-can-i-speed-up-image-load-time-in-my-web-site

Answer (score 1):

Antes tentar otimizar, precisa saber o que acontece.

No caso do PHP e MySQL (o outro BDD), nos temos 4 pontos:

1. tempo do tratamento do lado da BDD
2. tempo de tratamento do lado do PHP
3. tempo de transmissão dos dados, entre o servidor e o navegador
4. tempo de construção da pagina pelo navegador

Para o ponto 1 vc pode verifica usando isso:

```
 $start_time = microtime(true);   // Antes
 $result = @mysqli_query($handle,$query);
 $end_time = microtime(true);   // Depois
 $ecart = $end_time - $start_time;  // Diferença
```

Para o ponto 2, vc pode fazer do mesmo jeito: coloca um microtime(true) no inicio da pagina PHP, um na ultima linha, calcula a diferença e faz um "echo" do resultado.

Depois disso, vc vai poder ver se o tempo de exposição é idêntica à do cálculo: se o tempo de "PHP" é de 0.03 segundo, o tempo de Mysql de 0.01 que demora 3 segundos para ver a pagina, isso significa que o problema não acontece no Ponto 1 o no Ponto 2...

Sobre o Ponto 4, tem uma coisa a saber: não sei a estrutura da sua pagina, mas os navegadores iniciam a mostrar o conteúdo das paginas com tabelas, somente depois receber a totalidade do código.
Por exemplo, se vc tem 500 resultados (depois do query) e vc coloca os resultados numa tabela só (então que vc tem o tag TABLE no inicio da pagina, depois 500 tags TD e TR para os 500 resultados e no final da pagina o tag de fechadura do TABLE), o navegador vai esperar receber os 500 dados ANTES de iniciar o mostrar qualquer coisa.
Para evitar isso, precisa abrir e fechar a tabela, por exemplo cada 30 resultados. Assim, o usuário vai ver rapidamente os 30 primeiros, quando os outros resultados vão continuar chegar. Isso não vai mudar o tempo "real" mais vai mudar bastante a percepção do tempo!

Ultima hipótese: a sua ligação internet esta fraca.

PS: um detalhe. O modulo "mysql" é considerado obsoleto. Precisar usar mysqli.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica do MYSQLi